# passenger-install-apache2-module to run several applications on one server. Something not right

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache2, passenger

I've configured an Ubuntu server with passenger-install-apache2-module so that I can run several rails applications on one server. I've got a test application running which works fine using webbrick, but when I restart the apache server, I get the "We're sorry, but something went wrong" error. When I place a file in /public/index.html, that is rendered fine but as soon as the application relies on rails to generate content, I get the same error.

Where can I find the logs so I can find out more information? Or does anyone have a better idea?

UPDATE: I chmodded the log file, and now get this error in the production log:

```
Started GET "/users" for 77.100.43.95 at 2012-07-06 07:38:48 +0000
Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 115ms

ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
    2: <html>
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Max</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1047297680506537616_22545860'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

Thanks

Comment: Your application logs are under your application directory, /log subfolder, just like in development. And you should know your application directory from what you set it to in Apache configuration.

Comment: There's no production.log file... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

from within the application directory. This should fix the error.